# How can I run units tests in Docker container using alpine image and save the results?

Tags: node.js, docker

I am currently located within my folder of the vue.js project. The source files are located in ./src/ folder and test files are located within ./tests/

Usually to run unit tests locally I run the following commands:

```
npm install
npm ci
npm run test:ci
```

and it produces, among the others ./report/coverage.lcov file

However, I want to use node:12-alpine docker image to run unit tests inside of it. DO NOT offer to use Dockerfile. I want to run it using **docker run --rm node:12-alpine ....** and copy the content of ./report folder into my local folder when docker run command is complete. However, I could not figure out how I can do that? What docker run arguments I should use?

Comment: bind-mount a directory from your host to `./report`.

Comment: I tried docker run -v \`pwd\`/report/:\`pwd\`/report/ node:12-alpine --entrypoint "npm install && npm ci && npm run test:ci" 

but the folder is empty, any suggestions - full command?

Comment: I'd run the `npm run test:ci` command you show in the question, without Docker.  Do you have any reason to expect your unit tests would behave differently in a container or not (hopefully they depend only on Node and the installed libraries and not anything external)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I can do this and it is very simple

```
docker run --rm -v ${PWD}/:/tmp/run -u 0 --workdir=/tmp/run node:14-alpine npm install && npm ci && npm run test:ci
```

Answer (score 0):

Why bot mount your report target as a volume while running?

Comment: any chance to put a full command with docker run? Also, will the local folder content be preserved after running it?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to run it locally by creating script.sh file

```
cd /tmp/run
npm install
npm ci
npm run test:ci
```

in project directory and running:

```
docker run --rm -v ${PWD}/:/tmp/run -u 0 node:12-alpine sh /tmp/run/script.sh
```

This is great as I do not need to install another node version locally and container is deleted after run... However, I could not replace the last line via:
cd /tmp/run && npm install ... as it raised an error. Did not really wanted to introduce an extra script. Using --entrypoint outputs another error.